# jQuery PrintArea prints blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to print a form using jQuery print area, a custom stylesheet, and some javascript code. The actual site's page is:

```
http://dev.radioimagendigital.com/orden-de-servicio/
```

And the button that calls the print area action is "Imprimir", the css file passed as parameter to the PrintArea plugin is:

```
http://dev.radioimagendigital.com/wp-content/themes/stability/print1.css
```

And the actual javascript code is:

```
jQuery("div.b1").click(function(){
    var print = "";
    jQuery("input.selPA:checked").each(function(){
        print += (print.length > 0 ? "," : "") + ".content_orden_servicio" + jQuery(this).val();
    }); 


    var template_uri = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'; 
    jQuery(".content_orden_servicio").printArea({
        mode       : "iframe",
        standard   : "html5",
        retainAttr : ["id","class"],
        printDelay : 500,
        printAlert : true,
        extraCss   : 'http://dev.radioimagendigital.com/wp-content/themes/stability/print1.css'
    });
});
```

As soon as I try to print the form, I got a blank page. Why is that? and How can I solve this issue?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is only happening on Chrome. :/ And there are no javascript errors.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but: `rintDelay` should be `printDelay`

Comment: @mhu Thanks!, and yes, that's not the issue :(, It seems that even with the print option of the browser I can't print this page, but If I go to any other page on the site it prints just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CSS issue overall, somehow css managed to hide everything from the printer in chrome, to solve this I created a new iframe with the content and css rules I wanted to print and called jquery print area from it.